# Interface between applications running inside and outside a docker container

Tags: docker

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 and am using the Nvidia Riva Automatic Speech Recognition application to detect speech commands. I would like to direct/pipe them into another application to execute a control action. The problem I have is that the ASR application is deployed within a docker container and the control application is not.

Therefore. I would like to know how an application running outside the docker container may interface with an application running inside.

I have considered running everything inside the same container, however this is not practical because our product is mature, has lots of services interacting with each other, and also interfaces to linux kernel drivers.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, file access on the host will work for my control application. I have done a quick test of the volume option. It seems that the data written to file is only updated on the host when the application running on the container is terminated.

Comment: Communicating through a port may work. Your docker app have to send TCP (HTML?) or UDP packets of data and the host computer app has to listen to the port and know how to interpret these packets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two very obvious interfaces between a Docker Container and the host that you should probably explore further:

1. Published ports
2. Bind mounts (persistent storage)

###### Published ports

One option when running a container is to map ports from the container to the host. This can be used for web interfaces etc., but also to exchange other data via TCP or UDP port mapping.

To map a port between container and host, use the `-p` option with this syntax [following syntax](https://docs.docker.com/network/#published-ports):

```
docker run -p <host-port>:<container-port> <IMAGE>
```

Example: You want to map TCP port `80` in the container to port `8080` on the host (the `/tcp` is optional, since its the default).

```
docker run -p 8080:80/tcp <IMAGE>
```

###### Bind mounts

Another option is so use bind mounts to map files between the host filesystem and the container. These files are mapped in realtime, so any updates happening in the container should be immediately reflected in the filesystem.

To map files between container and host, use the `-v` option with this syntax [following syntax](https://docs.docker.com/reference/cli/docker/container/run/#volume):

```
docker run -v /path/on/host:/path/in/container <IMAGE>
```

Example: You want to map the path `/data` in the container to the path `home/user/data` on the host.

```
docker run -v /home/user/data:/data <IMAGE>
```

Note that additional mappings can also be done for single files:

```
docker run -v /home/user/data:/data -v /usr/local/etc/container.conf:/etc/container.conf <IMAGE>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. If I published ports 8080 and 80 does this mean I could communicate using a tcp socket using 127.0.0.1:80?
Also, I tried the -v option but found that the files were not updated in realtime. Anything written to the mapped file on the container side was only flushed to the host side after the application stopped running.

Comment: Yes, for ports. Also, if the data isn't written in realtime, then it must be a problem from within the specific container application, since this is normally the case.

Comment: Tests showed that a TCP Socket could communicate using the published ports. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: @user5265160 I'm happy that you seem to have solved the issue! 